# Node.js / Express / Mongoose - How to Send JSON along with view of Object?

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

I would like to pass the JSON object along with the view when I show a model Object in Node/Express using Mongo.

Curren route (passing just the view):

```
app.get('/page/:customurl', function(req, res, next) {
  Page.findOne({ customurl: req.params.customurl.toLowerCase()}, function(error, page) {
    if (!page) return next(new NotFound('Document not found'));
    res.render('pages/page_show.ejs',
      { locals: {
          title: 'ClrTouch | ' + page.title,
          page:page,
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Can I add `pagejson:page.toObject()` to the locals and then put `pagejson` on my page somewhere? When I tried that it showed up as [object, Object] at the browser. Is there any easy way to pass the JSON to the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at [JSON methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON)

In node repl:

```
> var document = {a: 'first property', b: 'second property'};
> JSON.stringify(document)
'{"a":"first property","b":"second property"}'
>
```

If you need to respond to the route in different ways (ex. requested via ajax) you can either pass a new parameter to the url `app.get('/page/:customurl.:format', ...` or checking the request headers stored in `req.headers`

```
if ( req.headers["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] === "XMLHttpRequest" ) {
  res.send(document);
} else {
  res.render(...);
}
```

Comment: cool. well what i want to do, and i don't totally know if this makes sense is respond to plain html get request with the object available as JSON. sort of like sending the view and then having the browser call .getJSON() and returning json. I would like to have the whole Page attributes available in JSON without having to call it from the browser.

Comment: @tuddy You can always set a `<script id="document_object" type="object/json"><%= JSON.stringify(page) %></script>` in yout templates, so you can have the object back via `JSON.parse($("#document_object").html());`.